Getting Linkedin Profile Data
I'm working on an app that helps you improve your LinkedIn profile, but I'm having trouble getting profile information (like job experience, projects, etc.) without scraping.
I've tried using the full_profile permissions, but that was apparently removed from Linkedin's API so I was wondering what alternative I can use
